# Is it possible to Pass set of table records from front end to back end using MVC3

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

i'm displaying a table in front end where table records are Editable and each record has a check box.

if some records are selected by making the corresponding checkboxes checked and submitted all the selected records have to be stored in a backend table.

Is it possible using Asp.net MVC3?

If yes how to pass that list of records from View to controller and Model?

Comment: You can pass the values from View to Controller using JSON and Ajax. Please post what you have tried (sample code). You can have a look at Dan Ludvig's BeginCollectionItem helper (http://www.nuget.org/packages/BeginCollectionItem/1.2.1 ), if you don't want to use Ajax. Please provide more information about your query in thepost.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand you want to pass array of selected checkboxes to ActionResult during post. 
See example below

**Model:**

```
public class EditableItemModel
{
    public bool SelectedItem { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new EditableItemModel[]
                        {
                            new EditableItemModel { SelectedItem = true },
                            new EditableItemModel()
                        };

        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(EditableItemModel[] tableItems)
    {
        IEnumerable<EditableItemModel> selectedItems = tableItems.Where(i => i.SelectedItem);

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

**View:**

```
@using CheckboxInTableExample.Models;
@model EditableItemModel[]

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index"))
{   
    <table>
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Length; i++)
    {
         <tr>
             <td>
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m[i].SelectedItem)
             </td>  
             <td>
                    @Html.EditorFor(m => m[i].Name)
             </td>      
         </tr>
    }
    </table>
    <input type="submit" title="Submit" />
}
```

Hope this helps.